# why installed new version of a package is not available in my virtual environment?

Tags: python, conda

I use to have yfinance 0.1.67 installed and today I installed a new version of yfinance 0.2.12 using conda install -c conda-forge yfinance. However I didn't see this new version. I was still using old version. so I decided to remove yfinance and do it again from start.

after removing all yfinance, I used conda list to show the all packages. and I don't see yfinance anymore. However, when I import yfinance, there is still yfinance old version

```
(dash_tf) C:\Users\test>python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yfinance as yf
>>> print(yf.__version__)
0.1.67
```

Now I use sys.executable to see which python I am using, and yes it is the python under the correct virtual enviroment

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.executable)
C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\dash_tf\python.exe
```

so now how do I remove this old version and install new version? Thanks

Comment: You've got multiple site-packages, you're managing one of them and using the other. At least that's the case 99% of the time.

Comment: ok, I solved it by doing conda update conda, then using pip uninstall yfinance. Thanks

Comment: As per duplicate, very likely the old version was installed in the user site.